# Unity : Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to lock my camera to a map I made in Unity3D using this code that was converted from JavaScript:

```
transform.position.z = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, zmin, zmax);
transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, xmin, xmax);
```

But Unity keeps on returning the following error while compiling: `error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of 'UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[About Compiler Error CS1612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c.aspx)

You shouldn't modify camera position that way.

Comment: The script is not meant to modify the camera position . Its meant to limit the camera to a max/min x and z value

Comment: In your code you say "new value of transform.position.z is Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, zmin, zmax)", but transform.position.z is a copy of original transform.position coordinate because of the fact that it is value type and it copies by value.
The proper way to clamp position (and also used in unity script reference):
> transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, xmin, xmax), 0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, xmin, xmax););

Comment: Thanks , i managed to clamp the camera to the map using the script above ,I had to modify it a bit . But it works :D

Answer (score 11):

because `Vector3` is a `struct`, means 'value type', not 'reference type'. so, the property `Transform.position`'s getter return a 'NEW' `Vector3` for result. if you modify it directly, the 'NEW' `Vector3` is modified, 'NOT' the `Transform.position` property. is that clear?

```
Transform.position.x = 0; // this is wrong code
// is same with
Vector3 _tmp = Transform.position; // getter
_tmp.x = 0; // change 'NEW' Vector3
```

this is obviously NOT what you want, so compiler told you that's a problem.

you should declare a new `Vector3`, and init with `Transform.position`'s getter, modify it, and change `Transform.position` with it's setter.

```
Vector3 _tmp = Transform.position; // getter
_tmp.x = 0; // change 'NEW' Vector3
Transform.position = _tmp; // change Transform.position with it's setter
```

don't worry about `Vector3 _tmp`, it's just value type, won't create memory fragmentations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the single coordinate of the position. You have to reassign the whole vector:

```
Vector3 newVal;
newVal.x = transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, xmin, xmax);
...
transform.position = newVal;
```