# Transform syntax usage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm modifying the transform of a simple cube.

```
float gravity = -0.25f;
myCube.transform.position.y -= gravity;
```

Doesn't work. error CS1612: Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.

```
float temp = myCube.transform.position.y;
temp -= gravity;
myCube.transform.position.y = temp;
```

Doesn't work. Same error CS1612: Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.

```
//Create temp gravity vector
Vector3 temp = new Vector3(0.0f, -0.25f, 0f);
myCube.transform.position += temp;
```

Which DOES work and so does this

```
private Vector3 cubePos;        
float gravity = -0.25f;
cubePos.Set(myCube.transform.position.x, (myCube.transform.position.y - gravity), myCube.transform.position.z);
myCube.transform.position = cubePos;
```

I understand how I can modify the transform with a vector (third example) or adjust the position with Set. But I still don't understand why the second example fails.

Can anyone kindly explain where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity : Cannot modify a value type return value of \`UnityEngine.Transform.position'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927720/unity-cannot-modify-a-value-type-return-value-of-unityengine-transform-positi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to translate a game object is:

```
myCube.transform.Translate(0, -gravity, 0);
```

Or

```
myCube.localPosition = new Vector3(
       myCube.localPosition.x,
       myCube.localPosition.y - gravity,
       myCube.localPosition.z);
```

References:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html

Answer (score 2):

"transform.Position.y" is a read only property so you can just read. Store the position in a Vector3 the modify that vector and then set it back to position e.g

```
Vector3 temp = cubePos.transform.position;
temp.x -= gravity;
temp.y -= gravity;

cubePos.transform.position = temp;
```