# how to understand transform.position+=new vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
transform.position+=new vector3(…)
```

position belongs to type value(struct),and new vector3 return type reference,why they can plus directly.

```
transform.position.x=1
```

why does it throw error,since srtuct.x=1 make sense

Comment: Question 1 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html
Question 2 https://stackoverflow.com/q/18927720/1092820

Comment: I don't know why you think `Vector3` is a reference type. It is a struct. What error does your second line cause exactly? I'm guessing it's something about trying to put an `int` value into a `float` property. Try `transform.position.x = 1.0f;`